# Where is my Google Analytics Tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

The instructions here actually appear to be 100% outdated. I see no "status" text anywhere on my site-specific page.
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55603

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming Q&A. Help using the Google Analytics website is off-topic. Voting to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is not outdated. Its instructions and video exactly mirror my interface. I followed the same steps and arrived at my tracking code.

"Check Status" is towards the top right of the page after you click "Edit" next to your website name.

[image: Google Analytics Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to Google Analytics
2. Click on the account you want (mine is "Paul's sites")
3. You will then see a list of sites and tracking codes ("Website profiles")

   http://www.mysite.ca  UA-XXXXXXX-1